# What exactly is my graphics card doing?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

I have an ASUS **A43SD** laptop with a built-in NVIDIA 610m graphics card.
I recently switched to Windows 7 64-bit and in the process did away with the NVIDIA driver I had installed. As far as I can tell, the computer has no idea it even contains a dedicated graphics card now. The Intel Graphics and Media control panel, which *is* installed,  seems to handle DirectX rendering and offers other 3D settings, and although I haven't tried any 3D-intensive stuff yet, I haven't noticed anything out of the ordinary about display or performance.

So, what exactly is my graphics card doing?

Is my computer using the graphics card at the moment?
Should I still try and download the NVIDIA driver to take advantage of the card?
Is there anything I should know about priority or conflicts among these control panels/drivers?

Comment: What model Asus laptop is it?

Comment: Edited to show.

Comment: Windows 7 probably got some sort of driver for it, as it does that by default typically.  Does your device manager show anything unrecognized or other errors in the video department?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You installed a generic video driver from Intel. This is [supported](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-022355.htm) - see section on that linked page called "Work-around", describing how it is possible to use the Intel graphics driver in such a manner, though they recommend against it.

Even though your 610M video processor is considered [entry-level](http://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-GeForce-610M.63759.0.html), there will be dedicated functionality that only a driver from NVidia will be capable of [tapping into](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-610m/features), such as:

1. Shader Model 5.0 support
2. NVIDIA CUDA
3. HDMI support
4. HD audio, which is tied to the mobile video card
5. HD video decoding

I suspect if you were to play an HD movie using your current setup, then install the latest supported 610M NVidia drivers, you'd find a noticable performance difference.